# Probability Distribution vague problem

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

A clerk at a convenience store leaves her counter unattended at 3:02 PM. When she returns at 3:08 PM, there is an impatient customer waiting at the counter. Given that the impatient customer did not arrive in the first 2 minutes, what is the probability that he arrived in the last 2 minutes of this interval?

Is there even a method to do this. Because there should be information about mean or the type of distribution. Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

the interval of unattended counter is 6 minutes long, that is the union of 3 equal intervals of 2 minutes long.

Given the fact that in the first 2 minutes nobobody arrived, the probability that the customer arrived in the last 2 minutes is $\frac{1}{2}$

EDIT: assuming uniform distribution of arrival times

Comment: Assuming uniform dist'n of arrival times.

Comment: @BruceET : thanks, specified in the edit